# How to stop a package from initializing with package-initialize on emacs (slime)

Tags: emacs, slime

I've been trying to get slime+sbcl working on my emacs (26.3) for a while. I first installed slime via melpa and that didn't work. I finally got slime able to work on a clean emacs (emacs -q) using quicklisp and the following code:

```
(load "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```

However, when I put it into my actual init file and run it, it doesn't work. I figured that if I put `package-enable-at-startup` to nil and commented out `package-initialize`, that slime works. My guess is that the installed slime through melpa is "overriding" the slime initialization using slime-helper. I can't uninstall slime via melpa because of package dependencies and am worried I might mess something up. But I also need all of my packages to initialize except slime. So I was wondering if there was anyway to initialize all my packages, but suppress the slime package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest method would be to disable the loading of "elpa slime" with `package-load-list`. See its documentation with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `package-load-list` <kbd>Return</kbd>. In short you'd put something like this in your *init file*.

```lisp
(require 'package)
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
             '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(setq package-load-list '((slime nil))) ;; don't load slime
(package-initialize)

(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```

`package-initialize` will skip loading `slime` (and manipulating your `load-path`), allowing the "quicklisp slime" to appear first on your `load-path`. This may or may not break dependencies loaded by the package system. If they do break, I'd see if `quicklisp` can manage them and deal with them that way, or I would manually manage them.